# Failed to save trace data to table - Profiler stops with this message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-profiler

I am trying to run profiler and get it to log to a database. The profiler starts to run and then after few hours (yes few hours, I know its bad!!) the profiler stops with the message.

```
Failed to save trace data to table
```

When I look at the logs, I can only find:

```
SQL Trace stopped. Trace ID = '2'. Login Name = 'sa'.
```

There are no other error messages. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Does the database containing the trace table have plenty of free space? Is autogrowth enabled? As a guess, it's possible that the DB is running out of space and/or it can't grow fast enough to avoid a timeout.

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, the database contains the trace table. There is a good amount of space and and autogrowth is also enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have grouping defined, you will receive that error if you try to save to table.
In "Trace properties" dialog, go to Events Selection->Organize Columns (button) and move everything from "Groups" section down to "Columns" section. Click OK, Run, and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If Network connection fails during this time, you might get "Failed to **save** trace data" or "Failed to **read** trace data" error messages.